# I don't understand why this python loop goes infinit

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm an absolute beginner at coding and only took some python courses at codecadamy. For the company I work, I now want to write a little script that generates pdf forms that can be filled out and whichs data later can be analyzed again (want to feed it to matplotlib). I'm done with the basics of the pdf form generator and editing the script for the toll that should extract data from it. Unfortunately this section of the code goes infinite and I can't wrap my head around why. Any help is highly appreciated!
fyi: data is a dictionary that contains specific key, value pairs I extracted from the pdf forms and of which I'm trying to group the keys as outlined in the latter code.

```
switch = 1
ends_counter = 1
extracted_calibre_data = {}
extracted_calibre_data_subdict = {}
while switch != 0:
    extracted_calibre_test = extracted_calibre_data.copy()
    for key in data:
        letter_check = ["e", "c"]
        if key[0] == letter_check[0]:
            if key[1] == str(ends_counter):
                if key[2] == letter_check[1]:
                    extracted_calibre_data_subdict[key[3]+key[4]] = data[key]
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
        extracted_calibre_data[ends_counter] = extracted_calibre_data_subdict
        ends_counter = ends_counter + 1
        if extracted_calibre_test == extracted_calibre_data:
            switch = 0
        else:
            continue
```

I tried writing a loop in python that groups keys and value pairs from a dictionary in differen sub dictionaries in order to plot them with matplotlib.However the loop goes infinite and i don't understand why.

Comment: This is coded in a confusing way. You should try to avoid `continue` statements in general. Maybe you can rewrite parts of it as multiple functions?

Comment: I'm guessing that the direct answer to your question is that `switch = 0` doesn't immediately jump out of a `while switch != 0` loop. The loop condition is only checked at the start of each pass through the loop.

Comment: if `key` does not start with `"e1c"` you loop forever.

Comment: As we don't really know what the contents of dictionary `data` are, and the code seems fine, i can only assume that the last `if `condition is never satisfied and thus loop runs infinitely. You can check by printing `extracted_calibre_test` to see whether its ever actually equaling to `extracted_calibre_data` .

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to simplify it to get some shorter program that will reproduce your behavior, or you can sprinkle some `print` across your loop to see what is happening, or even use `pdb` debugger.

In this case, the way I see it, the only way out of your loop is

```py
        if extracted_calibre_test == extracted_calibre_data:
            switch = 0
        else:
            continue
```

But right before that, you modify `extracted_calibre_data`

```py
        extracted_calibre_data[ends_counter] = extracted_calibre_data_subdict
```

And your `extracted_calibre_test` is set right before the `for` loop, so looks like there is no way for your loop to end. It is a bit hard to answer how exactly to solve this with limited information, but you can start looking there.